# Capture top command metrics directly in Solaris mode (i.e. Irix mode Off) to get average of CPU%

Tags: linux, performance-testing

I am using linux "top" command to gather performance metrics like CPU%, memory% using a python script in batch mode.

I tried passing

> **top -b -n1 -w512**

But since my system has 2 CPU cores, the above top command is summing up CPU% from both CPU cores and sometimes returning a CPU% more than 100%.

I read about Irix mode and Solaris mode and how we can switch between these modes using **Shift + i**.

But I am looking for a way to capture top command metrics **directly** in Solaris mode (i.e. Irix mode Off) using a script so that average of CPU% can be obtained.

**Platform: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to make “Irix mode” Off in “top” command so that average CPU% usage will be captured in batch mode.
Before running the python script, change the top configuration using following steps:

1. Run "top" command at the location where the python script is placed. It will display the top output with Irix mode ON which is the default setting.
2. Press "shift + i" to toggle the Irix mode to OFF.
3. Press "shift + w" to create a configuration file (.toprc) for top at the current location.

To confirm and check the top configuration file (.toprc):

1. Execute "ls -a -l" to show the .toprc file (it is a hidden file)
2. Open the file, you should see the Mode_irixps=0 (where 0=OFF and 1=ON)
3. Now onwards if top command is executed in the current location, then it will launch the top with Irix mode OFF.

If you want to use the top command with irix mode OFF irrespective of the location, then:

1. Change the user to “sudo -i” and navigate to /root directory
2. Run top command with sudo. (sudo top). It will display the top output with Irix mode ON which is the default setting.
3. Press "shift + i" to toggle the Irix mode to OFF.
4. Press "shift + w" to create a configuration file (.toprc) for top at /root directory.
5. Modify your top command in python script to "sudo top -b -n1 -w512"

Additional Info:
If the created .toprc File is removed, then the top command will display the output as default i.e. Irix mode ON.